# Does ENUM make a measurable difference in percentage of calls routed via IP vs PSTN?

Tags: voip, asterisk

I'm considering configuring this, but don't want to waste time if there isn't a significant cost saving to be made. Any advice would also be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Cost savings? Don't think so, but, as usual - it depends. ENUN-numbering will allow incoming calls to your SIP-URI (as you know) without using URI and DID-phones. Can it reduce costs or no?!